# How to transform sympy "vector" to numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I want to do a function and calculate its Jacobian, it helped me with sympy to derive but now I cannot value with numpy, as I was doing previously. I don't know how to pass every entry from Jacobian to a ndarray. since the type of Jacobian [1] [1] is sympy.core.add.Add and that when value is numpy.ndarray. but I don't know how to value either.

```py
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from string import ascii_lowercase as asi
vari=list(asi)[0:10]
var=sp.symbols(vari,real=True)
Funcion=[]
for i in np.arange(1, len(var)+1,1):
    if i==1:
        Funcion=Funcion+[(3-2*var[0])*var[0]-2*var[1]+1]
    elif i!=1 and i!=10:
        Funcion=Funcion+[(3-2*var[i-1])*var[i-1]-2*var[i-2]-2*var[i]+1]
    elif i==10:
        Funcion=Funcion+[(3-2*var[9])*var[9]-var[8]+1]

Jacobiano=[]
Gradiente=[]
for i in np.arange(0, len(var),1): #varia la funcion
    Gradiente=[]
    for j in np.arange(0, len(var),1): #varia la fila (lo mato a derivadas)
        Gradiente=Gradiente+[sp.diff(Funcion[i],var[j])]
    Jacobiano=Jacobiano+[Gradiente]
```

Comment: If you cannot ask a question in English without resorting to auto-translation, then you are most likely not able to understand and respond to the feedback you will receive here. This is an English community and the two versions in two different languages are not perceived as helpful. On the contrary, posts often get edited by helpful other users and they will be unlikely to bother about the non-English version - or refrain from doing their helpful edit. I recommend to delete the non-English version and find help from somebody fluent in English to support you in a smooth exchange here. Cheers.

Comment: Since your Jacobian has symbols in it is not very useful to convert it to a numpy array. Numpy can not understand sympy expressions. You can convert the list of lists to a sympy matrix with `sp.Matrix(Jacobiano)`.